# Laravel testing pagination with less data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to lower my test times.  Currently I have a test where I need to test the pagination links and meta data.

In my controller my pagination is set to 15 however in my test I have to create 16 instances using a factory to be able to assert the data on page 2.

TestGetStudents.php

```
public function testGetStudents() {
    Students::saveMany(factory(Student::class, 16)->make());

    $this->get('url/students/list?page=2')
         ->assertJson([
              'meta' [
                   'current_page' => 2 
              ]
         ]);
}
```

StudentController.php

```
public function list() {
    return Students::paginate();
}
```

How do I write the test without having to create 16 students to test data on the 2nd page?

Comment: I think ?page=2&per_page=8 would do it.

Comment: @TarekAdam Thanks but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Could you show the Controller code?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte The controller function is in my question under SudentController.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your controller to receive a paginate parameter from user:

```
public function list(Request $request) {
    $per_page = !($request->input('per_page')) ? 15 : $request->input('per_page');
    return Studentes::paginate($per_page);
}
```

Comment: So this code is only ever run during my tests. Do you think its ok to put code in your controllers that are purely for your test?

Comment: If you are using TDD you would get this problem before the implementation. So, the question actually is: should the code avoid the test? Or, if the desired behavior is to always have 15 Students, and you wan't to have 2 pages, you can't do it in a different way.

Comment: Ahh thats a shame. ok, I was hoping for some sneaky DI method but it seems if I want to correctly test this I have to change my controller code.